# Complex contour integral $\int_C \dfrac{cosh(z)}{z^4}dz$ where C is the square centered at the origin with side length 4

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, hyperbolic-functions, cauchy-integral-formula

Can somebody explain how to carry out the integral $\int_C \dfrac{cosh(z)}{z^4}dz$ where C is a square centered at the origin with side length 4? I know I'm supposed to use the Cauchy integral formula, but when I carry out the integral I get $2\pi i/6$. My textbook gives the answer as $0$.

Answer (score 1):

$f(z)=\frac{\cosh z}{z^4}$ is a meromorphic function with a single pole of order four at the origin.
 By the residue theorem, if $\gamma$ is any closed simple curve enclosing the origin, counter-clockwise oriented,
$$ \oint_{\gamma} f(z)\,dz = 2\pi i\cdot\text{Res}\left(f(z),z=0\right). $$
However, $\cosh(z)$ is an entire and even function, so a holomorphic function of $z^2$, and the Laurent expansion at the origin of $\frac{\cosh z}{z^4}$ contains no term of the form $\frac{1}{z}$. In particular, 
$$\text{Res}\left(f(z),z=0\right)=\color{red}{\large 0}.$$

Comment: I solved it this way as well; I am curious though as to why Cauchy's integral formula does not apply here. I cannot recall the exact hypotheses for Cauchy's formula but it seems odd that it should give an incorrect answer.

Comment: @Rellek: Cauchy's integral formula gives the correct answer, indeed. The residue is zero, hence the integral is zero as well.

Comment: The integral does turn out to be $0$. I accidentally wrote in my work that $\dfrac{d^3}{d x^3}cosh(z)=cosh(z)$ when it actually equals $sinh(z)$. Since $cosh(0)=1$, I got the wrong answer at first. By the Cauchy integral formula, we have that $\int_C \dfrac{cosh(z)}{z^4}=\dfrac{2\pi i}{3!}f'''(0)=0$ where $f'''(z)=sinh(z)$ and $C$ is the square described in the original question.

Comment: @JeffM.: I cannot agree more.